# How to align edit text areas horizontally

Tags: css

In the HTML code posted below, how can I make both of the edit text aligned to each other horizontally.

**html**:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="originLngLabel">origin Longitude:</label>
  <input type="text" id="originLngTextId" name="originLngText"><br><br>
  <label for="originLatLabel">origin Latitude:</label>
  <input type="text" id="originLatTextId" name="originLatText"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Meaure Distance">
</form>
```

**screen shot**:
[image]

Comment: @Arcteezy yes. and so that the distance separating them is to be customized pleas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this? Remove the br code to make them aligned to each other horizontally.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <span class="addClassHere" style="margin-right:10px">
     <label for="originLngLabel">origin Longitude:</label>
     <input type="text" id="originLngTextId" name="originLngText">
   </span>
  <span class="addClassHere">
      <label for="originLatLabel">origin Latitude:</label>
      <input type="text" id="originLatTextId" name="originLatText">
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="Meaure Distance">
</form>
```

Comment: yes exactly..but i would like to have some spacing separating origin Latitude label and the edittext to its left..in other words, i would like to add some spaces to the left of origin Latitude

Comment: ok cool, I added a style="margin-right:10px" on the span, that adds space to the right of the first block. You can style this better with stylesheets. If this is the correct answer, then hit me up with a correct answer.

Comment: hey..maybe this might be a question to you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66850915/how-set-value-to-input-text-area

Comment: page not found??

Comment: i just figured the answer out

Comment: can you please answer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851458/how-to-initialze-a-variable-of-type-number